# torch.cuda.is_available() returns false despite installing pytorch with CUDA

Tags: pytorch, anaconda, conda

running nvidia-smi gives,

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 528.33       Driver Version: 528.33       CUDA Version: 12.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ... WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   49C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    244MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

running `conda list pytorch` gives,

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
pytorch                   1.13.1              py3.9_cpu_0    pytorch
pytorch-cuda              11.7                 h67b0de4_1    pytorch
pytorch-mutex             1.0                         cpu    pytorch
```

running `nvcc --version` gives,

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2022 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Jun__8_16:59:34_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2022
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.7, V11.7.99
Build cuda_11.7.r11.7/compiler.31442593_0
```

For reference I have a GeForce GTX 1050ti

I've already tried uninstalling pytorch with conda and pip and reinstalling using,

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.7 -c pytorch -c nvidia
```

Answer (score 2):

So I deleted everything torch related and cuda related (found using conda list torch and conda list cuda) then reinstalled using

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.7 -c pytorch -c nvidia
```

and

```
conda install -c anaconda cudatoolkit
```

and it's working now